# Can you query Firebase App Indexing personal content?

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I have an app that implements Firebase App Indexing.  It also has its own full text search implementation.  Google's is obviously better, and I'd love to kill the one I'm using in favor of theirs.  Is it possible to query Firebase App Indexing for my own app's personal content?  I do not need/want any other app's content, only my own.

Comment: This sounds a lot to me like Firebase Personal Content Indexing (https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/personal-content), which is part of the Firebase App Indexing. I understand you want to access the results directly from within your app?

Comment: Yes.  It seems silly to be feeding Google's full text search and then having my own crappy one in my app.  Much nicer if I could query their''s.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to query the personal content indexing database. That's a great feature request though - you can file them directly through the Firebase support portal: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/